# Why do registers get overwritten upon overflow?

Tags: buffer-overflow, stack-overflow

I know that upon a overflow, the stack gets partially overwritten, but I do not understand why registers such as EIP or RIP get changed in this process.

How come some registers are modified by such an attack?

Comment: Where does that statement come from? a) not every overflow is a stack overflow, so be a bit careful with your wording and b) the act of the stack flowing over doesn't do anything to registers. So, I think your question is based on a false statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buffer overflows do not directly modify registers; rather, they are used to overwrite the function return address (the first element in the function's stack frame, `4(%ebp)` in x86) and place custom code on the stack which will be executed when the overwritten return address is loaded into EIP/RIP.

In x86 machines, the operations performed by `call` and `ret` are of particular interest:

- [`call`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html):

  > When executing a near call, the processor pushes the value of the EIP register (which contains the offset of the instruction following the CALL instruction) onto the stack (**for use later as a return-instruction pointer**). The processor then branches to the address in the current code segment specified with the target operand.
- [`ret`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html):

  > **Transfers program control to a return address located on the top of the stack**. The address is usually placed on the stack by a CALL instruction, and the return is made to the instruction that follows the CALL instruction.

Taking control of EIP/RIP is accomplished by overwriting the return address `call` pushed onto the runtime stack with an address that points to the location in memory of code crafted by the attacker. When the `ret` instruction writes this memory address to EIP/RIP, execution jumps to that address.

You can see this for yourself by stepping through program instructions using a debugger.